# passing image through binding context in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**I want is to pass an image into another page through bindingcontext**

This is the page where the image is already bound and when it is tapped I want to fetch it to another page.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"
    x:Name="image1"
    HeightRequest="200"
    WidthRequest="200"
    IsEnabled="True"
    Aspect="Fill"
    Margin="10">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer 
            Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" 
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

This is where I am passing the image to another page

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var page = new Page1();
    page.BindingContext = image1.Source;
    await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page);
}
```

This is the code of the second page that takes the image

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="Fill"/>
```

The problem is that the image is not showing the second page. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

As per your code, You have bound the second page with first page's image source. So, your second-page binding context is image source. So, you can use it as per my solution.

#### Solution

This is the code of the second page that takes the image

```
 <Image Source="{Binding .}" Aspect="Fill"/>
```

## Perfect solution

Create new property for image source (like ImageSource) in second page viewmodel and assign it from first page and use this property on second page like below:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Aspect="Fill"/>
```